# RabbitMq: Need help configuring the authentication cache plugin "rabbit_auth_backend_cache"

Tags: authentication, rabbitmq

I'm attempting to stand up a new RabbitMq server (Version 3.7.23, Erlang Version 22.2.3), and I've managed to get LDAP authentication working. Unfortunately, it seems that the authentication is quite slow, so my monitoring tools sporadically report errors when checking the aliveness endpoint and the UI occasionally shows a red "could not connect to server" error when navigating through the application that eventually goes away.

While researching my issue, it seems that the `rabbit_auth_backend_cache` plugin should help with this. I implemented the cache but it does not seem to be working. The rabbit log still shows Rabbitmq attempting to connect to LDAP for each request and I'm not seeing any errors that would explain what's going on with the cache.

Here is my config:

```
[
  {kernel, [

  ]},
  {rabbitmq_management, [
    {listener, [
                {port, 15672}
    ]}
  ]},
  {rabbit, [
    {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_cache,rabbit_auth_backend_ldap]},
    {cluster_partition_handling,autoheal},

{tcp_listeners, [5672]},

    {tcp_listen_options, [binary,
                          {packet, raw},
                          {reuseaddr, true},
                          {backlog, 128},
                          {nodelay, true},
                          {exit_on_close, false},
                          {keepalive, false},
                          {linger, {true,0}}]},

    {log_levels, [{ connection, info }]},
    {disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 1.5}},
    {vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.66},

    {default_user, <<"guest">>},
    {default_pass, <<"guest">>},
    {heartbeat, 60}
  ]}
    ,{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap, [
...omitted because it contains sensitive data...
] }}
    ]}
        ,{rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache, [{cached_backend, rabbit_auth_backend_ldap}, {cache_ttl, 5000}]}
        ,{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, []}
].
```

Here is what I'm seeing in the Log:
during start up:

```
2020-08-21 15:37:52.239 [info] <0.8.0> Server startup complete; 10 plugins started.
 * rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap
 * rabbitmq_shovel_management
 * rabbitmq_shovel
 * rabbitmq_federation_management
 * rabbitmq_top
 * rabbitmq_management
 * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
 * rabbitmq_management_agent
 * rabbitmq_federation
 * rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache
```

on shutdown

```
2020-08-21 15:37:44.095 [info] <0.43.0> Application cowboy exited with reason: stopped
2020-08-21 15:37:44.095 [info] <0.11984.0> Stopping application 'cowlib'
2020-08-21 15:37:44.095 [info] <0.43.0> Application cowlib exited with reason: stopped
2020-08-21 15:37:44.095 [info] <0.11984.0> Stopping application 'rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap'
2020-08-21 15:37:44.096 [info] <0.43.0> Application rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap exited with reason: stopped
2020-08-21 15:37:44.096 [info] <0.11984.0> Stopping application 'rabbitmq_management_agent'
2020-08-21 15:37:44.098 [info] <0.43.0> Application rabbitmq_management_agent exited with reason: stopped
2020-08-21 15:37:44.098 [info] <0.11984.0> Stopping application 'rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache'
2020-08-21 15:37:44.099 [info] <0.43.0> Application rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache exited with reason: stopped
2020-08-21 15:37:44.099 [info] <0.11984.0> Stopping application 'rabbit'
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting on some other forums, it looks like I just needed to up the TTL to 5 minutes instead of 5 seconds.

Thanks,
Alex